# d3 tracking overlay multiple lines

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How can I track the overlap of lines with text on top of each other, and if overlap occurs, then delete some of them?

The code was not added, because I am interested in the question, is it possible?

[image: diagramm]

Answer (score 1):

Decided with the help [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.your-class').forEach((el: any, index, blocks) => {
  const x_el = el.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  const y_el = el.getBoundingClientRect().y;
  const width_el = el.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const height_el = el.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  blocks.forEach((block: any) => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
    const {x, y, width, height} = block.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (((x_el > x && x_el < x + width) || (x_el + width_el > x && x_el + width_el < x + width)) &&
      ((y_el >= y && y_el < y + height) || (y_el + height_el >= y && y_el + height_el < y + height))) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: But its DOM, i want to do it with d3